# Driver bone not working

Tags: animation, bones, drivers

For some odd reason I can't get my driver bone to work. I've followed tutorials, but whenever I move the bone on the Z axis (local) to control whether my eye opens or closes, it doesn't do anything. :-/

[image]

Comment: you can upload the .blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I never seen any tutorials but I want to give it a shot

Comment: I've updated the original post

Comment: Its really too much for me, srry. Im going to have my existential crisis now.

Answer (score 0):

Your driver was working with local X movements, while moving a bone along its longitude is local Y axis. I changed the driver formula to "scripted expression" and multiplied the variable (named default "var", but you can change it) by - 10 for having consistency between bone and eyelid movement.

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get that working; it also says ERROR: Python auto-execution disabled. :-\

Comment: Okay, got the error message fixed, but I still can't seem to get that working. The Graph Editor really confuses me...

Comment: Didi you try to copy my two corrections? If yes you could upload your new file...

Comment: Actually, it does work. I was locking the other axis via the N properties bar. I would like for the changes to only work with the Z axis, but it appears it needs the Y axis for some odd reason. Is there anyway to fix that? Also, how can I adjust the speed at which the Shape Key animates via the Graph Editor?

Comment: Nothing odd (or, pehaps nothing completely odd): simply local coordinates are calculated related to the object (in this case the bone) and the bone has its y axis aligned with world's Z axis, so if you  move the bone along the world's Z axis, in fact you are moving the bone along its (local) Y axis. This is the difference between local and world coordinates, very useful because if the head is rotated the world coordinates will be twisted, but the local Y remains exactly local Y.

Comment: If you vary the angle of the line in the graph editor (select a point and use G for grabbing it) you will vary the speed of the movements (eventually you can also invert it). I prefer to use multiplications in the variable formula, but it's the same effect.